# How to Make This Jquery Script Work In Specific Width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm beginner to Jquery.
I have a simple piece of code that changes the height of an element to half of the window height.

```
$(function () {

    'use strict';

    $('.moubdi3in').height($(window).height());
});
```

I want to make this script work only when window size is more than 769px. In lesser heights, I want to give the element full window height.
How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `trinary` operator or `if` to decide what will be the elements height according to the current window height:

```
$(function () {

    'use strict';

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $('.moubdi3in').height(windowHeight > 769 ? windowHeight / 2 : windowHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make this script work only when window size is more than
>   769px

```
if($(window).height() <= 769) return; // reject function if less|equal 769px
```

> I want to give the element full window height.

```
$('.moubdi3in').css('height', $(window).height()); // set windows height to height property of .moubdi3in element
```